# Bootstrap : Custom Media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

i want to  implement following styles for 900 to 1023px

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -15px

}
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    border-radius: 0
}
.navbar-nav.pull-right {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    margin:10px 0 ; 

}
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    display: none
}
.nav-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    overflow: visible!important
}
```

i applied following media query

```
 @media screen (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1024px) { 

// here goes above code 

}
```

but problem is that  these stlyes are being applied on 1300 + resolution as well . whats wrong with it please help

Answer (score 0):

You miss `and` after `@media screen`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1024px) { 

// here goes above code 

}
```